# How to get Rosewill rnx-n250pce wireless card to work in Debian?

Tags: debian

I am using a rosewill rnx-n250pce wireless card on Debian. I can do lspci, and my wireless card will show up, but I am not able to use it, and it does not show up in iwconfig.

I tried installing drivers using using the drivers found [here](http://www.rosewill.com/products/1870/ProductDetail_Download.htm), and [this](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x#Installation) tutorial, I tried to install drivers.  However, this did not change anything.

There are errors in dmesg about being unable to load firmware.  The errors are specifically:

```
[    3.572022] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin

[    3.572499] rtl8192ce 0000:06:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin (-2)

[    3.572534] rtl8192ce 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2

[    3.572540] rtl8192ce 0000:06:00.0: Falling back to user helper

[    3.572993] rtlwifi: Firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin not available
```

While researching how to fix this, I saw something about compiling drivers.  Do I need to do this? If so, how do I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dmesg report anything about firmware missing?Output of iwconfig?

Comment: It does not show up in iwconfig, but I do see errors about it being unable to load firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[    3.572993] rtlwifi: Firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin not available`

Do this(use lan wired)

```
apt-get -y update;apt-get -y install apt-file
apt-file -y update
```

Then

```
apt-file search rtl8192cfw.bin
```

And the package returned you will install with apt-get -y install

```
apt-get -y install "nameofpackagereturned by apt-file"
```

Then reboot,or if you know the module used by wifi unload and reload with modprobe,after reboot/reload recheck with iwconfig

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: Feedback please,touch the J under V on my answer